# Do not want to group same node of xml while converting xml to json in c#

Tags: c#, json, xml, json.net

I am trying to convert xml to json.
I have multiple `<QUESTION>` tags inside this xml. I want to read this tag and depending on some condition have add one attribute.
But when I convert xml to json it is group Question node into a single group and it is difficult to update specific QUESTION node.
I'm using Newtonsoft.Json for conversion.

```
   <QUESTION DATAFIELD="FolderID" REQUIRED="1" HELP="0" HIDDEN="1" PROVIDELOOKUP="0" TYPE="SELECT"><SECTIONBREAK /><HEADING>Organization</HEADING>
    <DEFAULTANSWER>
    <SOURCE>SQL</SOURCE>
    <VALUE>
    <![CDATA[IF EXISTS(SELECT inodeid as sValue, sorgpath as sText 
     FROM OrgTree o 
     INNER JOIN Locations L ON L.NodeID = o.inodeid 
     WHERE o.sType = 'Folder') BEGIN

     SELECT sValue, sText FROM (
       SELECT '' AS sValue, '' AS sText
       UNION  
       SELECT CAST(inodeid AS varchar(50)) as sValue, sorgpath as sText 
       FROM OrgTree o 
       INNER JOIN Locations L ON L.NodeID = o.inodeid 
       WHERE o.sType = 'Folder'
     ) t ORDER BY sText

    END
    ELSE BEGIN
     SELECT sValue, sText FROM (
       SELECT '' AS sValue, '' AS sText
       UNION  
      SELECT CAST(inodeid AS varchar(50)) AS sValue, sOrgPath AS sText 
      FROM OrgTree WHERE sOrgPath LIKE (SELECT sOrgPath FROM OrgTree WHERE INodeID = 1)+'%' AND sType = 'Folder'
     ) t ORDER BY sText

    END]]>
    </VALUE>
    </DEFAULTANSWER>
    <ERRORTEXT>* Required</ERRORTEXT>
    <LABEL />
    <TOOLTIP />
    <COMMENT />
    <METRICSCHECKCOLUMN />
    <METRICSCHECKCONTROL />
    <SECONDARYCHECKBOX />
    <SECONDARYCHECKBOXACTION />
    </QUESTION>
    <QUESTION DATAFIELD="sOrgPath" REQUIRED="0" HELP="0" HIDDEN="1" PROVIDELOOKUP="0" TYPE="TEXT">
 <SECTIONBREAK>
        <GROUP>LINKS</GROUP>
        <QUESTION DATAFIELD="LinkedActions" REQUIRED="0" HELP="0" HIDDEN="0" PROVIDELOOKUP="0" TYPE="">
            <SECTIONBREAK />
            <DEFAULTANSWER>
                <SOURCE />
                <VALUE></VALUE>
            </DEFAULTANSWER>
            <ERRORTEXT />
            <LABEL />
            <TOOLTIP />
            <COMMENT />
            <METRICSCHECKCOLUMN />
            <METRICSCHECKCONTROL />
            <SECONDARYCHECKBOX />
            <SECONDARYCHECKBOXACTION />
        </QUESTION>
        <HTML>
            <![CDATA[]]>
        <COMMENT />
    </HTML>
</SECTIONBREAK>
```

Comment: Can you show a specific example of the XML you want to convert, and the JSON you want to convert it to?

Comment: and json format is like this

Comment: Your XML is invalid, try validating at http://www.xmlvalidation.com/ and you will get an error that there are extra nodes at line 40.  Can you give a complete example of your XML that shows where the problem is?